# How do you multiply n[g]_c? That is, multiply an integer by a number mod c.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am posed with a question in the form of $n[g]_c$. Would I multiply it normally as if $n$ was $[n]_c$? Thanks for any help.

Comment: In what context did you encounter this? Your guess is correct, but there are various ways to explain why this is the case, depending on what level of abstraction you are at.

Comment: It is for a homework problem in abstract algebra, I have to prove something and the left hand side is n[g]_c.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer a somewhat more general question: If $n$ is an integer and $a$ is an element in some arbitrary ring, what does $na$ mean?

There are two ways to view this (they give the same answer):

Multiplying some $x$ by a positive natural number $n$ is the same as adding $x$ to itself $n$ times. Multiplying it by $0$ should of course just give $0$, and multiplying it by a negative integer $n$ would then make the most sense if it meant adding $-x$ to itself $n$ times.

And the above is precisely what we mean when we multiply an element of a ring by an integer. But there is a slightly more abstract way to view this, which explains why the above is the "correct" way to do things.

If $R$ is a ring (with $1$) then there is a unique homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$, let's call it $\varphi$. So instead of multiplying by some integer $n$, we could multiply by $\varphi(n)$ (which is now an element of $R$, so the multiplication makes sense inside $R$). And indeed, this gives precisely the multiplication I described above. But could we do something differently?

It turns out that no, we cannot, at least as long as we want the multiplication by integers to behave "nicely". By nicely, I mean that we want the usual rules like $(n+m)a = na + ma$ and $(nm)a = n(ma)$, since these rules will mean that the multiplication in fact gives us a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$, and hence we are back at the above.

In your specific example, the map $\varphi$ is precisely given by $\varphi(n) = [n]_c$, so your guess was correct.

Comment: A fine answer, although the question sounds a bit like the OP may have never heard of rings.

Comment: @Myself Good point. The OP mentioned that this was for a course in abstract algebra, so I immediately jumped to "has seen rings", though that certainly need not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Myself is correct when stating that I have not heard of rings. Just started my undergrad abstract algebra class. I am sure we will get to rings eventually though!

Comment: You should be able to comment on my answer even though you do not have $50$ reputation, since it is an answer to your own question.